# Can't generate graph using graphviz and dot layout

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, pygraphviz, pydot

I am using `pygraphviz` 1.6 to generate the a plot using Python 3.6. Unfortunately, I can't update Python.
While generating the graph, the command `graph.layout("dot")` generates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-d73a7e09eb44>", line 6, in <module>
    graph.layout("dot")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1422, in layout
    data = self._run_prog(prog, " ".join([args, "-T", fmt]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1387, in _run_prog
    raise OSError(b"".join(errors).decode(self.encoding))
OSError: libpath/shortest.c:324: triangulation failed
libpath/shortest.c:200: destination point not in any triangle
Error: in routesplines, Pshortestpath failed
```

In order to reproduce the issue, you must download the file graph_data.txt from https://drive.google.com/file/d/12YjB752SfCrzHmycRDeYAH2PHL6gMiIJ/view?usp=sharing , and run the following code:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
with open("graph_data.txt", "wb") as fp:
    graph_data = fp.read()
graph = pgv.AGraph()
graph.from_string(graph_data)
graph.layout("dot") 
graph.draw(settings.PIPELINE_GRAPH_PATH, format="pdf")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @sroush I uninstalled graphviz and reinstalled it building from scratch.
The following is the code to do that:

```
apt purge graphviz && \
  pip uninstall graphviz && \
    apt install -y libgts-dev && \
    pkg-config --libs gts && \
    pkg-config --cflags gts && \
    wget https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/4207231/packages/generic/graphviz-releases/5.0.0/graphviz-5.0.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf graphviz-5.0.0.tar.gz && \
    cd graphviz-5.0.0/ && \
    ./configure --with-gts && \
    make && \
    make install
```

Note that you may need to run some of the above commands with `sudo` as done here: https://github.com/ellson/MOTHBALLED-graphviz/issues/1237#issue-226453389

Answer (score 1):

Curious!
There are several Graphviz issues open with similar descriptions.  https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1323 seems useful.  But no current solution.
However, I can't get your example to fail on my Linux system (Mint)!  Even when using a years-old Graphviz version.
So, old Python does not seem to be the problem.
OS-related, maybe?
Triangulation library (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1269), maybe.
Resulting file is 6M (png), too big to upload.

Comment: Thank you! What version of the graphviz and triangulation libraries are you using?

Comment: dot - graphviz version 5.0.0 (20220707.1540)
According to http://gts.sourceforge.net/, the latest release is 0.7.6 (March 29th 2006)